# Saving a file to a staging folder in Azure DevOps

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm executing a Powershell script in an Azure DevOps release pipeline. In the script some JSONs are saved to a local directory, which later in the script are then uploaded to Azure Blob Storage.

However, of course, Azure DevOps doesn't see my local directory to save to. Can I save the JSON files to say a staging folder in the Azure DevOps agent? Or if not where can I save to when the script is run in the release pipeline? Thanks

Comment: Did you look at the pre-defined variables available in the scope of a release? `System.DefaultWorkingDirectory` maps to your agent's working folder. Look at the documentation for more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save the json file to a folder in azure devops agent. When the agents run your pipeline, it will create a working space with below folders in the agent machine.
You can point to these folders in your pipeline by referring to the predefined environment variables.

For example :

> $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) is mapped to folder '/_work/2/a'
>
> $(Build.BinariesDirectory) is mapped to folder '/_work/2/b'
>
> $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) is mapped to folder '/_work/2/s'

You can also save the json file to a new folder(eg. staging folder) within '/_work/2'.
For example `$(Agent.BuildDirectory)/staging`. A new folder staging will be created within folder`/_work/2`.

[image]
[image: enter code here]

For more informatin about predefined variables. Please check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml). For release variables please check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch).